# Multiple mountpoints on one partition?

Tags: mount, partition, root, home

Can I have separate `/` and `/tmp` but `/home` + `/var` on one partition somehow?

Separate `/tmp` is good because I can set it up with some quick unreliable filesystem. I often change distributions therefore separate `/` is a blessing - quick re-install and I'm good as long as `/home` and `/var` are untouched.

The problem is, I don't want to designate space for any of the last three - I want them to share available resources. I sometimes need more space in `/var` and I can see there's available space in `/home` that I cannot use, sometimes it's the other way around. It's frustrating. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't separate `/` and `/usr` anymore. You can't do reinstalls leaving `/usr` untouched either (and `/var` not completely).

Comment: Why? Any sources on that? What is a good practice regarding partitions separation then?

Comment: @Cyprian, https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/  (it's by the systemd folks but not directly related to it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always mount your third partition somewhere (like `/mnt/combo` or something), and then bind-mount subdirectories from this mountpoint to the three designated directories.

In `fstab`, this would look something like

```
UUID=... /mnt/combo        auto    defaults
/mnt/combo/usr /home        none    bind
/mnt/combo/var /var        none    bind
/mnt/combo/home /home        none    bind
```

Also consider this: `/home` makes sense to live on a separate partition - even better, a separate drive, which can be somehow protected (raid, backups,...). `/var` would make sense to be separate if you really have something personal in there (websites and such), otherwise it makes no difference. `/usr` can definitely be part of `/`, it makes no sense to have it separate because on a modern system, the distinction between `/bin` and `/usr/bin` is blurred and noone cares about it anymore, and segmenting a system only creates problems if one of the partitions somehow doesn't mount.

`/tmp` should normally be ram-backed anyway (`tmpfs`), unless you really are running out of RAM, and most distros do that by default unless you change it.

Big picture: separate `/home` if you have to, the rest is just overhead - you probably have no reason to have different filesystem types or different permissions on any of these, and partitioning doesn't usually mean physical separation (same hard drive?).

Comment: How would that work during reinstall? Each time I reinstall it would write to `/home`, `/usr`, `/var` on root partition and afterwards I would manually "replace" mountpoints with `/home`, `/usr` and `/var` from my `/mnt/combo`?

Comment: Yes, that would work, if that's what you want. But then, what does a reinstall even do? You usually want to keep configuration, so keeping `/etc/` is more important than the rest, and there isn't much outside `/usr` anyway on a fresh install (`/boot` and that's it). If you *want* the install to write to these partitions, you'll simply have to mount this before running installation.

Comment: @CyprianGuerra take a look into kickstart files. They automate tasks during installation. If you're worried about the configuration disappearing between installs a kickstart can help you out.

Comment: Okay, I'm marking this as a valid answer because it resolves my question... I have to re-think my idea of reinstall, though, but this is a separate issue. And no, I don't think I want to keep configs because I use reinstall as the last resort when I'm lost trying to fix whatever I broke and need a working system ASAP, default configs, default packages.

Comment: In that case, in my opinion, it's better to wipe clean the /usr too. Because package repositories change. Things get updated. Very likely, old applications wouldn't work with fresh install. I would strongly recommend to just have a list of packages you want... and write a script that would quickly install everything, always the same things - and maybe simulatenously fix the things you want personalized (hostname, network config,...). A simple shell script that does the full system install. Otherwise you'll spend hours debugging when compatibility breaks.